# Custom marker icon not working

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet and want a custom marker icon. React-leaflet can take a Leaflet.Icon object to display a custom marker icon. So I NPM installed leaflet, and added `import { L } from 'leaflet';`.

I then added:

```
const FPIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
  }
});

const purpleIcon = new FPIcon({
          iconUrl: '%PUBLIC_URL%/markers/Bar-Marker.png'
        });
```

to my render method.

But I keep getting the following error `Cannot read property 'Icon' of undefined`.

To achieve a custom marker icon, I've also tried the following:

```
const purpleIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '%PUBLIC_URL%/markers/Bar-Marker.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
});
```

but again got a `Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined` error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the second example the bracket are not closed correctly, remove `}` at the end. And what happend if you use an url like https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png ?

Comment: Good spot, although I didn't have that rogue bracket there when I tried it, I've just tried with the url above and it makes no difference :(

Comment: And if you `console.log(purpleIcon)` ?

Comment: Undefined, it's crashing on `const FPIcon = L.Icon.extend({`

Comment: Can you post all of the code from the file?  I can't be sure, but my guess is that you're not importing leaflet, so the L variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your leaflet import is wrong. Import leaflet as follows after that it will work as expected:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Below component to add custom marker

https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/144

Comment: Please copy concerned content, links can be changed or removed

Comment: That component is restrictive and doesn't allow for a png image to be added as the marker, like I am trying to do above, plus it's designed around Google not Leaflet.